# Convert a string to unsigned long long int in C

Tags: c, string, unsigned

How can I convert a string to an unsigned long long int?

The problem is that if I use `strtol` that returns a long int, but I need to convert a string longer than that.

Comment: There's always [`strtoll`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol). If you need even bigger than that, you might want to look into a bignum library such as [GMP](http://gmplib.org/).

Answer (score 9):

There is [`strtoull()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoull) which sounds like a very good    match:

```
unsigned long long int strtoull(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);
```

No idea why you didn't find it.

Comment: Thank you. I searched but really fast I'm doing a project to college and it's the first time that I'm programming...Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strtoll` for `long long` type.

You can also use `sscanf` with `%ll` format specifier to convert to `long long`.

Also, you can write your own implementation if it does not fulfill your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

[`strtoll`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoll) should do what you want.

Answer (score -1):

if only there was a standard library function that SCANned a Formated String... sscanf maybe